# finding an injective homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

Question: Show that there exists an injective homomorphism

$$r:\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\to S_{27}$$

whose image is contained in the union of two conjugacy classes of $S_{27}$

My solution I thought:

I know that two permutation are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure.

I thought to take a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\to\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$
such that if  $f(a,b,c) = (f_{1}(a,b,c),f_{2}(a,b,c),f_{3}(a,b,c))$, then for every $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ and for every $1\le i \le3$ $$f_{i}(a,b,c) =  \begin{cases} 0&, (a,b,c) = (0,0,0) \\
                       \neq 0 & ,otherwise \\
                     \end{cases}$$
Using this function I thought to take the homomorphism $$r(a,b,c) = (1, 2,3,...,9)^{f_{1}(a,b,c)}(10,11,12,..,18)^{f_{2}(a,b,c)}(19,20,21,...,27)^{f_{3}(a,b,c)}$$

My problem is that I don't know how to find this kind of function,

Any help for finding  this kind of function or for alternative solution for this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are approaching this too abstractly. Hint: start by listing the elements of order $3$ in $S_{27}$ since those (with the identity) must contain the image of your homomorphism. What are the conjugacy classes. Can you map to two of them?

Answer (score 1):

There is an elementary abelian group $H$ of order $9$ that lives in $S_9$ and is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ with three fixed points each:
$$H:=\langle a, b\rangle\text{ where }a=(1 2 3)(4 5 6),\;b=(4 5 6)(7 8 9)\;$$
Now let $t$ be the three-fold "shift" of the range $(1, \ldots, 9)$:
$$t:=(1\;10\;19)(2\;11\;20)(3\;12\;21)(4\;13\;22)(5\;14\;23)(6\;15\;24)(7\;16\;25)(8\;17\;26)(9\;18\;27)$$
Then $a^\ast:=a\cdot a^t\cdot a^{t^2}$, $b^\ast:=b\cdot b^t\cdot b^{t^2}$ and $t$ generate an elementary abelian group of order $27$ (and thus an injective image of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$) in $S_{27}$ that contains some elements with $9$ fixed points and some with no fixed points, i.e. elements from two conjugacy classes.